# How to Calculate CRC8 in Java

Tags: java, crc

I have a binary String of "011001000010100100100010001000100100100100", how do I calculate CRC8? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [Jacksum](http://www.koders.com/java/fid5EECB1CAEC4D566A888B12126B11E7EF78D98F75.aspx).

From a Google search of CRC8 java.

Comment: funny, i did the same search and i wound up here.  maybe leave out the commentary in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of packages that contain this functionally built in. Of the top of my head I recall that jFLAC has it on their jflac.util.crc8 class.